# Printing text from text files in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below prints the text like this:

```
 John
  Smith
  02/07/1234
```

Firstly it indents two of the lines, how would I change the code to print it as:
`John Smith 02/07/1234` on one line?

```
with open("Forename") as f1, open("Surname") as f2, open("Date of birth") as f3:
    for forename, surname, birthdate in zip(f1,f2,f3):
        print (forename, surname, birthdate)
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
with open("Forename") as f1, open("Surname") as f2, open("Date of birth") as f3:
    for forename, surname, birthdate in zip(f1,f2,f3):
        print("{} {} {}".format(forename.strip(' \t\n\r'), surname.strip(' \t\n\r'), birthdate.strip(' \t\n\r')))
```

the *.strip(' \t\n\r')* removes leading and trailing tabs returns and spaces, the *.format()* formats your string to print in a nice control-able way.

Comment: If you use strip() without arguments, then it trims all whitespace chars, so calling e.g. forename.strip() would suffice.

Comment: Also, add some spaces to the string itself between the brackets :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.join` and strip the whitespace from each name.

```
with open("Forename") as f1, open("Surname") as f2, open("Date of birth") as f3:
    for forename, surname, birthdate in zip(f1,f2,f3):
        print(' '.join([forename.strip(), surname.strip(), birthdate.strip()]))
```

Answer (score 1):

As your questions does not explicitly specify Python, you may want to know that you do not need any program at all, if you are on a unixoid system (BSD, Linux, Mac OSX): just use the `paste` shell command:

```
paste -d ";" forename surname birthday
```

will yield

```
John;Smith;02/07/1234
```

if you do not specify the `-d` flag, a tab will be used to separate the entries. You may learn more about `paste` here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("Forename") as f1, open("Surname") as f2, open("Date of birth") as f3:
    for forename, surname, birthdate in zip(f1,f2,f3):
        print (forename, surname, birthdate, end=' ')
```